# Add Artifacts to Team City from External Location

Tags: teamcity

I am looking to set up a build on my Team City server that needs to use a dll from an external source (network path).

I was wondering if there was an easy way to manually create artifacts in team city from network locations either via REST API or Powershell/Command Line runners.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a script (bash/BAT etc) that will fetch the DLL for you using i.e. cURL, wget or other tool like that. Run that as separate step before starting your tests and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marcin

How do i then make the dll that I have retrieved visible to the Team City test build runner?

Do you have any simple example?

Comment: While each job is separated from each other, steps are not, so your working dir (or subfolder) is the right place to put that stuff and next step will see it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Build Configuration: "External Resources"

- Build Step: Command Line

  `mkdir Resources`

  `xcopy Z:\lib\ ./Resources`
- Inside the Artefacts Rules, specify:

  `Resources/*.dll`

Create a Build Configuration: "External Resources"

- Add a Snapshot dependency on `External Resources`
- Add an Artefact Dependency on `Resources/MyLibrary.dll`

Comment: This answer is more useful than the approved answer for my use case.  I want to add config files on each build.  The contents of the config files differ slightly for each destination server.  I don't have any of these files available from a network path.  I want to just add and maintain the files in TeamCity directly.